# where can I find all the properties for jquery UI.Item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
select: function(event, ui) {
}
```

Where can I find all the properties and methods for the UI parameter that jquery provides to methods using the jquery ui?

Comment: http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: It depends on what the event is. Read the docs. For example: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/menu/#event-select

Comment: I think inspecting in chrome dev tools will give you a good break down that is specific to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/). For instance, if you were looking at the [`change` event of the autocompleter](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change), you'd see that `ui` has an `item` property, which is *"...The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is `null`."* But if you  were looking at the [`slide` event of the Slider widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide), you'd see that `ui` has `handle`, `value`, and `values`.